# UPDATE table with two $_POST values?

Tags: php

If I have an array of names, and points how can I INSERT this data into mysql?

**Names:** *result of `$_POST['playername']` mentioned below*

```
matt
john
kevin
ryan
anthony
mike
luke
brian
eli
zach
derrick
kobe
```

**Points:** *result of `$_POST['points']` mentioned below*

```
3
12
0
27
0
0
11
0
5
8
0
1
```

The points match up with the names.

In my code I have a foreach name running a block that contains stats for each name. The block has the player name and an input that captures the points the player scores.

```
<li class="name">
<span><?php echo $player ?></span>
<input type="hidden" name="playername[]" value="<?php echo $player ?>" />
</li>

<li class="points">
<span>0</span>
<input type="hidden" name="points[]" value="0" />
</li>
```

So there is going to be the same amount of `$_POST['playername']` as `$_POST['points']` in the same order.

How do I update a table that has a points column and names column?

```
 $player = $_POST['playername'];
 $points = $_POST['points'];

"UPDATE stats SET points = $points WHERE player = '$player'"
```

I need to run a foreach loop but if I do the same loop as foreach name mentioned above then looping the `$player` or `$points` loops the correct amount of times but only one value.

SO I am not sure how to do an `array_combine` here or if I should use a different approach I know its easy but I cant figure it out. Pretty sure I need to loop the `$_POST` variable, but I think I also need to combine them.. I am all scrambled up, so to figure this out just put yourself as the developer and you need to update the `points` table to match up with the right `player` table

**EDIT:** *Thanks to posters below I can now work with both arrays better.*

But to extend this question, it's weird when I use a variable to update the table it wont work. When I enter it manually it works `$sqlupdate = "UPDATE stats SET points = 22 WHERE player = 'matt'";` any idea why it wont work with a variable?

Comment: a for loop? `for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)`...

Comment: the issue is should I loop the `$_POST` variable and if so I am not sure how to insert both values to match.

Comment: can you not `explode()` each of the post variables to create seperate arrays then foreach them and run the queries?

Comment: I rarely have used explode() except for once, I saw an example using it, I dont think I gave the example a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$player = $_POST['playername'];
$points = $_POST['points'];

foreach($player as $key=>$value)
{
    $sql="UPDATE stats SET points = $points[$key] WHERE player = '".$value."'";// in place of $value you may also use $player[$key]
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this echoes nicely, I am having a hard time updating the table though.. let me fiddle with it.. this sets me in the right direction.

Comment: This worked well for me, as far as printing each array, but the table wont UPDATE with a variable, I have to enter it in manually.. `$sqlupdate = "UPDATE stats SET points = 22 WHERE player = 'matt'";` using this exact code.. I tried with others and its the same

Comment: I think its something on my end. let me tweak some stuff

Comment: Its okay dude, this was good anyway.. I figured it out, it was something on my end I forgot I had more point values then there were names. A few tweaks to iron out but this worked well.. Probably should use `mysqli_query` though

Comment: Then how do you correlate a `point-player`-pair if their count differs? This code will process them sequentially in order. is it okay for you purpose?

Comment: oh it will match up.. its just I have a home list and an away list.. each player is under both, but I only inserted the names once so I had 12 names and points value are doubled at 24.. I just need to create either another table for home, and another for away or something..

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful, cant believe I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<?
  for( $i = 0; $i<count($player);$i++ ){
      $sql = "UPDATE stats SET points = $points[$i] WHERE player = '$player[$i]'";
      //execute sql here
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hmm let me try it.. should be quick brb

Comment: Yeah this works just like Rajesh's code, I dont use for loops often though, nice to mess with them more.. works good, but still struggling with the update.. will post back soon :)

Comment: Its weird because when I `$sqlupdate = "UPDATE stats SET points = 22 WHERE player = 'matt'";` insert manual info, it works.. but not when there is a variable..

Answer (score 1):

```
for( $i = 0; $i<count($_POST);$i++ ){
    $sql = 'UPDATE stats SET points = '.$_POST["points"][$i].' WHERE player = '.$_POST["playername"][$i];
    //execute sql
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just altered Jorge code bit,

```
<?php

 $player = $_POST['playername'];
 $playerCount =count($_POST['playername']); // one time count check

 for( $i = 0; $i<$playerCount;$i++ ){
        $PlayerVal = trim($player[$i]); // empty value check
         if($PlayerVal!=""){
              $sql = "UPDATE stats SET points = "'.$points[$i]'" WHERE player = '".$player[$i]."' ";
           //execute sql here  
         }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks im messing with some code now trying to get it to update the table, when I do that Ill play with this to see which I like the most..